# Scrapy - Scraping links by date

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

Is it possible to scrape links by the date associated with them? I'm trying to implement a daily run spider that saves article information to a database, but I don't want to re-scrape articles that I have already scraped before-- i.e yesterday's articles. I ran across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245910/scrapy-how-to-scrape-daily-for-new-pages) SO post asking the same thing and the [scrapy-deltafetch plugin](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-deltafetch) was suggested.

However, this relies on checking new requests against previously saved [request fingerprints](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/utils/request.py#L19) stored in a database. I'm assuming that if the daily scraping went on for a while, there would be a need for significant memory overhead on the database to store request fingerprints that have already been scraped.

So given a list of articles on  a site like [cnn.com](http://www.cnn.com/specials/last-50-stories), I want to scrape all the articles that have been published today 6/14/17, but once the scraper hits later articles with a date listed as 6/13/17, I want to close the spider and stop scraping. Is this kind of approach possible with scrapy? Given a page of articles, will a `CrawlSpider` start at the top of the page and scrape articles in order?

Just new to `Scrapy`, so not sure what to try. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I don't think it's built into `scrapy`, but considering that the article urls _should_ be in the format `/2017/06/14/politics/two-arrested-brawl-turkish-embassy/index.html` have you thought about parsing the date from the url and comparing it?

Comment: @etemple1 Unfortunately, in this case `cnn.com` is just an example site and not the site I would like to scrape. Most of the sites I would like to scrape do not include the date in the URL

Comment: Ah, ok. So how do you know the "date associated" with a link?

Comment: @etemple1 Well, some sites with an article list page have the date of the article listed in the article preview. Of course, with sites that don't, I would actually have to make the request, and then pull the date information from the article.... After which, if the article was a previous date void saving the article information and stop all further requests by closing the spider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I compose a date using `datetime.strptime(Item['dateinfo'], "%b-%d-%Y")` from cobbled together information on the item of interest.

After that I just check it against a configured age in my settings, which can be overridden per invocation.  You can issue a closespider exception when you find an age that is too old or you can set a finished flag and act on that in any of your other code.

No need for remembering stuff.  I use this on a spider that I run daily and I simply set a 24hr age limit.

Comment: Thank you!! Just wondering, do you use a `CrawlSpider` when implementing this? Given that articles are in a list with the newest appearing at the top of the page, I simply wanted to close the spider when I hit the first "previous" date. But `CrawlSpider` doesn't parse the article links from top to bottom, meaning that it skips around the page, and I cannot stop requesting immediately. I'm trying to avoid having to request all articles on the page... but given that `CrawlSpider` doesn't go in order, is that impossible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom delta-fetch_key which checks the date and the title as the fingerprint.

```
from w3lib.url import url_query_parameter

...

def parse(self, response):
    ...
    for product_url in response.css('a.product_listing'):
        yield Request(
            product_url,
            meta={'deltafetch_key': url_query_parameter(product_url, 'id')},
            callback=self.parse_product_page
        )
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to see if I can use an approach without `deltafetch` as mentioned in the question but also as it uses `Berkeley DB` and I'm not sure if its compatible with the `MongoDB` I want to use